# priority_queue declaration and bool operator < declaration

Tags: c++, priority-queue

my problem is:

- I have my program with 2 class plus the main;
- I've declared a priority_queue inside a member function of a class;
- I have to define the comparison and I think the code I should use is:

  ```
  // Determine priority (in the priority queue)
  bool operator < (const node & a, const node & b)
  {
    return a.getPriority() > b.getPriority();
  }
  ```

Question: where Should I insert this piece of code? Could someone help me?

thanks

Comment: Why don't you make it a member function of `node`?

Comment: because I get an error: too much parameters for the function "operator"

Comment: Member operator functions can only take 1 parameter: `bool operator<(const node& other) { return this->priority < other.priority; }` should do it if you write it inside the class definition. Or `bool node::operator(const node& other) { ... }` if it's outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your `operator<` is possibly a poor addition to `node`. Ask yourself: are nodes logically comparable? Is it clear that comparing nodes (outside of the context of priorty_queue) should compare their priority? Maybe it should compare their position, or anything else they might contain. If you supply an `operator<` it will also make sense to have the other 5 comparison operators. If it's not clear what `node < node` actually compares, don't provide an `operator<` for nodes. In cases like this it's better to provide a custom comparer to the `priority_queue`...

```
struct NodeComparer
{
    bool operator()(const node& left, const node& right)
    {
        return left.GetPriority() > right.GetPriority();
    }
}
```

...

```
std::priority_queue<node, std::vector<node>, NodeComparer> nodeQueue;
```

This way your `priority_queue` can work as desired but you don't add illogical functionality to `node`.

Comment: Ok, I've got what you mean. The problem remains: I have a priority queue inside a member function of a class A, and I have defined separately a class "node". Where have I to insert your code???

Comment: I have putted the struct just above the class which contains the member funtion which uses the pq....now it seems to work! Thank you for your great advise

Comment: @user1783116 you could also nest the struct in the class which contains the `priority_queue`, as private preferably since it's an implementation detail of that class.

Answer (score 0):

This operator should be visible where the priority_queue is declared. As the priority queue exists only in a member I would place the operator's definition right above the given method definition in the `.cpp` file that implements the method.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The actual problem is that "node" is a class, "A-star" is another class inside which I've the member function where i have used a priority_queue. How can I do?