# Prioirty Queue operator error in C++

Tags: c++, priority-queue

I'm trying to insert a part of `struct node`s into a priority queue based on the Compare function as shown in the following snippet.

```
struct node
{
    string line;
    int length;
};

struct Pair
{
    node first,second;
};

struct Compare
{
    bool operator()( const Pair* p1,  const Pair* p2)
    {
        return p1->first.length > p2->first.length;
    }
};

int main()
{
    ...
    priority_queue<Pair*, vector<Pair*>, Compare> PairsQ;
    ...
}
```

I get the following error among several other similar lines.

`error: no match for ‘operator<’ (operand types are ‘const Pair’ and ‘const Pair’)
       { return __x < __y; }`

What's the solution? Why do I see this error even though I've defined the compare function.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The error you posted mentions a type (`ResPair`) which is not listed in your question.

Comment: Also note that the comparator function is supposed to get values/const references as parameters, not pointers.

Comment: @Barry, it is just Pair. I edited it. There are other functions but they aren't related to this error.

Comment: @REACHUS : I have defined the compare function for that. Doesn't it take this to be the function when comparing two `Pair` objects in the priority_queue

Comment: Cannot reproduce: http://ideone.com/RNIUv3

Comment: I'm using the first solution shown here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14981590/priority-queue-declaration-and-bool-operator-declaration

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you want to create queue of `Pair*` instead of `Pair`?

Comment: No. I'm getting the same error even if I create a quue of just `Pair`.

Comment: @clcto : http://ideone.com/kLTuUI The whole code.

Comment: @Aiyoyo I am not going through your whole code. You need to create the [MCVE], and in doing so, you may find the problem yourself.

Comment: @Aiyoyo That's totally different than the code in your question! There, your comparator takes `ResPair&`, here it takes `Pair*`.

Comment: @Barry, both gave me the same errors. I was trying out suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When providing a comparator function to an STL container like `std::queue`, your `operator()` function should have the following signature:

```
bool operator()(const Pair& p1, const Pair& p2)
```

Then (parts of) your program would like like (I have changed type from `Pair*` to `Pair` as you have commented that it is not a requirement here):

```
#include <string>
#include <queue>

using namespace std;

struct node {
    string line;
    int length;
};

struct Pair {
    node first, second;
};

struct Compare {
    bool operator()(const Pair& p1, const Pair& p2) {
        return p1.first.length > p2.first.length;
    }
};

int main() {
    priority_queue<Pair, vector<Pair>, Compare> PairsQ;
}
```